# Finding nested iFrame using Selenium 2

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am writing tests for a legacy application in which there is an iFrame within the main document, and then another iFrame within that. So the hierarchy is:

```
Html Div (id = tileSpace)
  iFrame (id = ContentContainer)
    iFrame (id = Content)
      Elements
```

This is my code (I am using C#)

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
var tileSpace = driver.FindElement(By.Id("tileSpace"));
var firstIFrame = tileSpace.FindElement(By.Id("ContentContainer"));
var contentIFrame = firstIFrame.FindElement(By.Id("Content"));
```

The problem is, I am unable to reach the 2nd level iFrame i.e. contentIFrame

Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm currently testing on a similar website. (nested iframes inside the main document)

```html
<div>
    <iframe>
        <iframe><iframe/>
    <iframe/>
</div>
```

It seems that you are not using the **[frame switching method](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames)** provided in Api. This could be the problem.

**Here is what I'm doing, it works fine for me.**

```cs
//make sure it is in the main document right now
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();

//find the outer frame, and use switch to frame method
IWebElement containerFrame = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ContentContainer"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(containerFrame);

//you are now in iframe "ContentContainer", then find the nested iframe inside
IWebElement contentFrame = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Content"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(contentFrame);

//you are now in iframe "Content", then find the elements you want in the nested frame now
IWebElement foo = driver.FindElement(By.Id("foo"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
    //Switch to required frame
    driver.SwitchTo().Frame("ContentContainer").SwitchTo().Frame("Content");

    //find and do the action on required elements

    //Then come out of the iFrame
    driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```