# How to switch to sequential iframes on the page

Tags: selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario, where I need to click an image within dynamically changing iframes. I am able to click ONLY on the first image on the page. The script does not recognize the iframe afterwards, and gives me TimeoutException. This is my script below:

```
//get the First iframe 
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id, 'adnxs_tag_')]")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id, 'adnxs_tag_')]")));
```

Then I switch to the next iframe on the page

```
//get the second iframe 
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id, '336')]")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id, '336')]")));
```

Comment: There is no pop-up window, though!

Comment: Ya my bad. That was related to window. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130871/finding-nested-iframe-using-selenium-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **switch to the default content** before switching to the next frame:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id, 'adnxs_tag_')]")));

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id, '336')]")));
```

Comment: @familyGuy just to make sure: are you waiting for the second iframe after switching to the default content?

Comment: I added this, but still getting timeout. Wait is 20.      driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id, 'adxns')]")));
 driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id, 'adnxs')]")));

Comment: @familyGuy first, please recheck your xpath. Also, is the second frame located on the same level as the first one, or are they nested? Thanks.

Comment: I asked the developer to add some static id to the div. It was just a waste of time to capture dynamic iframes on this page. Thanks for all of your help!, and your answer is definitely acceptable.